# Bar Button Item in TableViewCell is not registering in didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2, uibarbuttonitem, didselectrowatindexpath

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    selectedRow = indexPath.row
    articleUser = userids2[indexPath.row]
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("jump", sender: self)
}

@IBAction func Share(sender: AnyObject) {
    shareArticleUrl = articleUrls[selectedRow]    
    shareText = "Check Out This \(shareArticleUrl)"
    let activityVC:UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [shareText], applicationActivities: nil)
    self.presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

I currently have a toolbar in each cell of a tableview. After the update to Swift 2, when a bar button item is selected, instead of running the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` function first it instead jumps directly to the `share` function. I need to use the `indexpath.row` in the `didSelect` function to select the proper item in the `articleUrl` list. The technique above worked fine until the update to Swift 2.

I have tried to incorporate `let selectedIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(sender as! UITableViewCell)` in the `share` function but I haven't been able to make that work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you set the tag on your tab bar as row number while adding it in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and then in your `Share` function just retrieve it from the passed in `sender`.